# What is the energy stored in a temperature gradient?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, calculus

Let's say, i have a block of iron, which is 10cm thick and on the top surface, the temperature is 10°C and at the end surface is 5°C. So what is the energy required to maintain this temperature gradient.

I am looking for the formula we will use and how will we go about solving it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier's law of heat conduction?

Comment: The question in the title and in the body of the question are different. If I am constantly putting in energy to maintain the temperature gradient, it is clearly not storing energy

Comment: Without knowing how the cold end is maintained (thermal conductivity to the outside world), it seems the best you can do is to use the sheet thermal constant of Fe to calculate the energy flow rate per cm^2 of cross-sectional area to maintain a delta temperature of 5 K over 10 cm.   In any case, a thermal gradient is not like an electric field: it doesn't store energy in that sense.